# How to add more than one information into JQuery Mobile List view

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, cordova

I am getting JSON data (list of Hotels available with in given distance). I am getting following information in JSON format, Name of Hotels, Distance of Hotel from our current location, number of rooms. There may be more than one Hotels in the given distance. We have to  print all these information in **ListView** like below. I want to combining the all informations like in following figure of a Hotel into a single listview.

[image]

**When we click any list of hotel, It will redirect to Hotel site or More details dedicate Hotel page.**

**Javascript code is.**

```
    <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
                $("#btnReg").click(function(){ 
                    $("#listOfHotelOption").empty();
                    var distance = document.getElementById('distance_id').value; 
                    var output=""; 
                    $.ajax({ 
                            url:"http://192.168.1.4/Experiements/webservices/getBuddy.php", 
                            type:"GET", 
                            dataType:"json", 
                            data:{type:"login", Distance:distance}, 
                            ContentType:"application/json", 
                            success: function(response){ 
                            console.log(response) 
                                $.each(response, function(index,value){ 

                                 output+="<li>"+value.Hotel.Name+" "+value.Hotel.Distance+" " +value.Hotel.Rooms+"</li>";
                                }); 
                            $("#listOfHotelOptions").append(output).listview().listview('refresh'); 
                        }, 
                            error: function(err){ 
                            alert(JSON.stringify(err)); 
                        } 
                    }) //ajax 
                }); //click 
            }); //ready 
    </script>

**My server site code is** 

<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');//Should work in Cross Domaim ajax Calling request
mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
mysql_select_db("hotels");
if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
    if($_GET['type']=="login"){
        $distanceInKM=$_GET['Distance'];       
        $query="Select * from Hotels where Distance<='$distanceInKM'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $totalRows=mysql_num_rows($result); 
        if($totalRows>0){
            $recipes=array();
            while($recipe=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $recipes[]=array('Hotel'=>$recipe);
            }
            $output=json_encode(($recipes));
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "Invalid format";
}
```

Comment: You want to format the list items to look like the picture you have?

Comment: @Tasos, sorry Please ignore previous comments, I was trying like that output+="<li>"+"<img alt=\""+uu+"\" src=\""+vv+"\" width=\"'20px'\" height=\"'20px'\" >"+" "+value.Hotel.Name+" have "+value.Hotel.Rooms+"available"+"</li>"; also every list show be click able and redirect to dedecated hotel page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a demo with grabbing data from the list items and close to the format you want to achieve

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/0m3pxznf/

**Jquery** to grab data from the list items you use `<li data-whatever="abcdcd"` ... etc and grab them upon click.

```
$(document).on("click", "#hotels >li", function () {
var hotelname = $(this).closest("li").attr('data-hotel');
var rooms = $(this).closest("li").attr('data-rooms');
alert(hotelname + "--" + rooms)
})
```

**Html**

```
<li data-hotel="taj" data-rooms="10"><a>
    <img src="http://s30.postimg.org/9evb4kq65/album_bb.jpg">
        <h2>Hotel:<span class="hotel">Taj</span><span class="avail">Available Rooms:<span class="rooms">10</span></h2>
        <p>Distance:<span class="distance">10km</span></p> <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/3qio5rxeb/album_p.jpg" class="sideimg"></a>

</li>
```

**Css**

```
.sideimg{
 position: absolute;
right:0 !important;
top: 0 !important;
max-height: 5em !important;
max-width: 5em !important;
}

 .ui-listview>li h2 {
margin-top: -5px !important;
}
.ui-listview>li p {
margin-top:10px !important;
}

.hotel, .rooms { padding-left: 5px; }


.avail { padding-left: 15px; }
```

**Result**

[image]

If you want to redirect users to the hotel sites then put in the list items `data-url="the-url"` and grab it in the click function and use `window.location.href = theurlvariable;`

Comment: @neelabhsingh no problem. see also last note to redirect to the hotel sites

Comment: K, this is the same we are discussing yesterday, now Today I need to print all information for particular hotel and put in single list view and when we click list It redirect to the dedicate hotel page or hotel site